# Android Cursor Management w/ListView

Tags: android

I've got a ListActivity that displays a list of items from a database using a CursorAdapter, which initially contains all items in the table. I also provide an EditText view where the user can enter search text, and as characters are entered, I requery the database using a "LIKE" or "MATCH" where clause to filter the results (IOW, what lots of apps do when searching).

Currently, I do this in an AsyncTask by creating a new Cursor from the query, creating a new instance of my CursorAdapter class, and then calling list.setAdapter from the UI thread when the task completes. This is all working, but is there a more elegant way of effectively requerying the database with a new WHERE clause from withing the existing adapter/cursor and avoiding having to create new object instances each time? Any examples of this technique?

Doug Gordon
GHCS Software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `CursorAdapter` has an `changeCursor`-Method, were you can change the `Cursor` without changing the adapter itself. When changing the Cursor the corresponding `AdapterView` will automatically be notified and update itself.

For further abstraction, you might provide a business object that wraps the query and optionally the execution of the query and provide it to both the `Adapter` and the `TextView` (or the Activity possessing the TextView). The `TextView` changes the business object, the object creates a new cursor and tells the Adapter (using the Observer Pattern, e.g. a Listener) that the cursor changed, and the Adapter retrieves the new Cursor and updates itself.